# Folder Permissions Document Library

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

We are migrating all our users filer server data to SharePoint. One thing we are having issues with is they want unique permissions. For example

- Folder A - Johnny Salesman (1 person)

  - Folder B (inside of folder a) Johnny Salesman  & other sales people
  - Folder C (inside of folder a) Johnny Salesman & Another sales person
    etc etc

How is it possible to achieve this

Comment: How are you planning to accomplish this? Are you using 1) PS script 2) MS Flow/Power Automate etc?

Comment: I was thinking of doing it manually at first to test but then powrrshell most likely cause there is allot of folders.

Comment: For PowerShell to work, you need to create a csv file containing  folder names and user names or group names that you want to grant permission to. Then loop through the folder names in the file and retrieve each folder from SPO and then grant permission as defined in the csv file. I think, it's doable.

Answer (score 0):

You could set unique permission for three folders.

For example, select the folder A -> click ellipsis -> shared with -> advanced -> stop inheriting permissions -> grant permission to Johnny.

After set unique permission for folder B, Johnny and other sales can directly access folder B through the URL of folder B.

But at this time, Johnny can access folder B through URL and UI, other sales can only access folder B through URL, not in UI.

References:

[Customize permissions for a SharePoint list or library](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/customize-permissions-for-a-sharepoint-list-or-library-02d770f3-59eb-4910-a608-5f84cc297782)

[Change the permissions on a subfolder](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-the-permissions-on-a-subfolder-5427bd7c-f20a-4f75-8cf2-5359dd45a1a6)